# How can I convert this SQL query using COUNT, SUM, CASE, and BETWEEN into Perl DBIx::Class?

Tags: sql, perl, between, dbix-class

How can I convert this SQL query into Perl [DBIx::Class](http://p3rl.org/DBIx%3a%3aClass) code?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_grads,
       SUM(CASE WHEN employment_status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_employed
  FROM students
 WHERE status = 6  -- 6 means they graduated
   AND grad_date BETWEEN Convert(datetime, ?) AND Convert(datetime, ?)
```

Comment: Do you mean DBIx::Class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you mean DBIx::Class, then I'd probably go for something like:

```
my $rs = My::Schema->resultset('Students') #
    ->search({
        status => 6,
        grad_date => { 'between' => [ $start_dt, $end_dt ] },
    });

my $num_grads    = $rs->count();
my $num_employed = $rs->search({ employment_status => 1 })->count();
```

Of course the datetime bit will depend on your datetime formats, whether you are automatically inflating/deflating datetimes etc

Comment: That's two separate queries, isn't it?  Yuck.

Comment: This answer is passing my tests so far. Thank you!

Comment: @ysth - yes, it's two separate queries, but it's easy to read and test and seems more in keeping with DBIx::Class - i.e. you're dealing with resultsets of matching objects, rather than trying to replicate SQL queries directly. Building complex queries with SQL::Abstract as used by DBIx::Class can be quite frustrating, and sometimes impossible (other than passing sections of SQL directly). If they were heavy queries then I'd try and combine them, but a COUNT() on a propertly indexed table shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The problem is that the data may change between the two queries.